# Invalid left hand side assignment onclick javascript button

Tags: javascript, custom-object

I have a custom button which checks for the following condition but I'm getting an error like "Invalid left-hand side assignment :

**Display Type:** Detail Page Button

**Behavior:** Execute Javascript

**Content Source**: Onclick Javascript

Code:

```
if( 
({!Lead.Content_Approval__c} == True && 
{!Lead.Relations_Approval__c} == False &&
{!Lead.Final_Approval__c} == False &&
{!Lead.Approval_Confirmation__c} == True && 
{!Lead.Relations_Approval_Confirmation__c} == False &&
{!Lead.Approved__c} == False) 

){ 
    if (confirm('Are you sure you want to log this activity?')) { 
    // Fire away! 
    window.location.href = "/apex/sampleleadbatch?scontrolCaching=1&id={!Lead.Id}"; 
    } else { 
            // Go back to the Lead page 
        } 
    } 
else { 
alert("Please get approved the  Lead before hitting 'Send'."); 
}
```

Comment: Are you encountering this when you're trying to compile your code?

Comment: Are you using Salesforce Classic or Lightning?

Comment: salesforce classic

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have a few problems with your code. Let's start with the first one: Boolean values are not capitalized in JavaScript, and JavaScript is case sensitive. That means you should use `true` and `false` instead of `True` and `False`.

Secondly, there's no reason you need to compare to `true` or `false` directly; simply use the value for true, or its inverted value for false. Third, you can combine all of your checks into a simple formula:

```
if({!Lead.Content_Approval__c && NOT Lead.Relations_Approval__c &&
 NOT Lead.Final_Approval__c && Lead.Approval_Confirmation__c &&
 NOT Lead.Relations_Approval_Confirmation__c && NOT Lead.Approved__c}) {
  if(confirm(...)) {
    // Do action
  } else {
    // Go back
  }
} else {
  alert(...);
}
```

Finally, you can write a slightly more optimized version by swapping around some Boolean logic:

```
if(
{!
AND(
  Lead.Content_Approval__c, Lead.Approval_Confirmation__c,
  NOT(OR(
      Lead.Relations_Approval__c, Lead.Final_Approval__c, Lead.Relations_Approval_Confirmation__c
    )))}) {
  if(confirm(...)) {
    // Do action
  } else {
    // Go back
  }
} else {
  alert(...);
}
```

You can do this because `NOT x AND NOT y` is the same as `NOT(x OR y)`.

Comment: +1 for don't compare Booleans to Booleans.

Comment: +1 for suggesting use of [DeMorgan's Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan's_laws) to simplify an expression.